# Blocking Airdrop in company?

Tags: bluetooth, ios

I understand that Airdrop is used via bluetooth, and then temporarily connects to a device, creating a private network between the two (or multiple) devices. With that said, I am assuming the only way to stop Airdrop from happening in a specific vicinity (say, work location) is simply to teach everyone how to turn off Airdrop/disable bluetooth?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Airdrop requires *both* bluetooth and wifi: you could set a no peer-to-peer wifi policy and enforce.

If the desktop machines involved are owned and managed by the organization, you can set organizational preferences to disallow airdrop on *those* machines, but that will not prevent individual iOS users from sharing files on their devices.

Best practise is already that users should only allow Airdrop from existing contacts.

If the goal is a hard ban on this protocol, you could require use of a device policy management suite for anyone whose device comes into the network regularly, such as [***jamf***](https://www.jamf.com/products/jamf-pro/device-management/) and set appropriate policy there.

Comment: However, they don't actually need to be connected to a wifi network - They just have to have wifi turned on. So the policy would be ineffective if the person never connects to it. Unfortunately we can't do the other suggestions as we have BYOD, with tight budgets. Thank you for the suggestions, It is certainly appreciated and great ideas!